# Passing Variable Number of Arguments to an Entry in a Char* Array

Tags: c, error-handling, string-formatting

I have been using the following link: https://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4215552/Seventeen-steps-to-safer-C-code to enhance the current error logging of a project I am working on.

My end goal is to generate an enum "error type". I would map these error types to a lookup table of char*'s which I could use to log a more detailed explanation of what the error is.

This way, I have all my error codes and corresponding error strings in a central location and can easily modify/lookup a message and errorcode without having to dig through the code.

As a PoC, my header file contains the following:

```
typedef enum {
    ECODE_OK = 0,         // OK
    ECODE_SAMPLE_ERR = 1,
    ECODE_LAST
} myEcodes;

char * ecodeMap[ECODE_LAST+1];
char * ecodeName(myEcodes err);
```

My implementation in C of the header is included below:

```
char * ecodeMap[ECODE_LAST+1] =
{
    "No error to report",
    "Example Error Code - Invalid Value",
    "Last ecode place holder"
};

char * ecodeName(myEcodes err)
{
    return (char *) eyescanEcodeMap[err];
}
```

My question is, say I have the following code snippet to log an error I encountered:

```
fprintf(fp, "%s", ecodeName(ECODE_SAMPLE_ERR));
```

What if I want ECODE_SAMPLE_ERR to actually contain a formatted string like

```
"Example Error Code - Invalid Values: %d %d", myVarInt1, myVarInt2
```

instead of just

```
"Example Error Code - Invalid Value"
```

What would be the best way to be able to format individual strings in my array of char* such that I can include the value of variables in particular entries?

Comment: how many formatted strings do you expected to use? that is - how many different types of the formatted strings will you have ?

Comment: It depends on the error. Some may just be strings with no formatting, i.e. `"You have lost connection to the device"`. Others may have several variables, i.e. `"The current laser settings for DAC %d, pulsewidth %d, and period %d resulted in an invalid laser power %f", var1, var2, var3, var4`. I would say most won't need errors and only a very small number would ever need more than 5 variables inserted into the string

Comment: I don't understand something. Is the actual log function calling `fprintf(fp, "%s", get_error_string(error_code));`. *Forgive me*  for changing the names, I tried to type it like you did but I couldn't.

Comment: I think these 2 links can help you out :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180695/c-function-to-return-formatted-string

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28622895/calling-a-function-within-fprintf-syntax-in-c-language

Comment: I hope you do know that the statement: `strerror( error );` will return a suitable string for most error conditions.  However, for errors specific to the application, something like this: In the code: `CommonWriteCdsLog(  eLL_Critical,
            get_pFormatString( eFormat_CFFL_string ),
            __FILE__, __LINE__,
            "LibFunc:popen() failed for 'bin/date'"); ` worked very well for  me. were ` get_pFormatString()` selected from a table of format strings and `eLL_Critical` was from a `enum` of values to determine if the message was to be logged. and the  (cont)

Comment: cont: `eFormat_CFFL_string` was from a `enum` to select which format string and `__FILE__, __LINE__, "LibFunc:popen() failed for 'bin/date'"` were the values to be incorporated into that message. (cont)

Comment: (cont) the function: `CommonWriteCdsLog()` formated the string using a `cast` statement for each format string enum and finally wrote the resulting message to the log.  You could generate a table of messages and use a `enum` to select which text from that table

Answer (score 1):

If the main aim is to add print along with other variable values, let ERROR string be constant. You can just add additional values when you are writing to file fp.

```
fprintf(fp, "%s: %d %d", ecodeName(ECODE_SAMPLE_ERR), myVarInt1, myVarInt2);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there will be times I need to actually insert the variable values into different parts of the string, not just append them onto the end

Comment: It's best to keep the error codes simple. These kind of ERROR codes are meant to be constant. I don't understand why you have to append in between these strings. May be you can change the strings to be as simple as possible and generic.